# How should I add a user email address for a user with ASP.NET Identity 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have a WebAPI application and I would like to add an email to the information I store for each user. Although there are many examples out there I am not sure those are now the recommended way to go with Identity 2. In particular I notice that Identity 2 now has extension methods to deal with email.

[UserManagerExtensions.FindByEmail Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497473%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

But how can I store the email so that I can use this extension method?  Do I need to store it here and if so can I store it as a claim ?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager) {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    // I don't want to add email here 
}
```

However I am not sure how to do this:

- Should I some add the email into the above where it says "// Add custom user claims here" and if so then how would I do that?
- Should I make a change to the registration method below and if so then how should I do that?

  ```
  [AllowAnonymous]
  [Route("Register")]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
  {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          return BadRequest(ModelState);
      }

      IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
      {
          UserName = model.UserName
      };

      IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
      IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

      if (errorResult != null)
      {
          return errorResult;
      }

      return Ok();
  }
  ```

I would appreciate some advice on how to do this. Note that I am using a token based approach with claims in an Identity2 application. If possible I am looking to do this with claims and not just by adding columns to the user table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [IdentityUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class already contains a property for the email address, so there's no need to duplicate that. You only have to set that property during the registration process, similar to the following snippet

```
IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
{
    UserName = model.UserName,
    Email = model.Email
};
```

Don't forget to extend your **RegisterViewModel** and the **Register** view with that additional property and field.